# Create a Spring framework Crontrigger trigger working between two dates

Tags: java, spring-boot, triggers, scheduler

I'm developing an application with user defined triggers and I need to use Java and Spring framework.

Is there a way to create a Trigger with the CronTrigger expression, which runs every 10 minutes, every day between two different dates?

I think this is possible using Quartz, where CronTrigger has setStartAt() and setEndAt() methods, but with Spring CronTriggers it seems impossible to me.

Thanks!

Comment: You already answered yourself. Spring crontriggers are simple triggers for patterns and that is it. It is not a full fledge library like Quartz or JobRunr.